# Event Receivers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Where can we implementthe event receiver?
I am new to the SharePoint so please guide me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Event handlers are something "similar" to the **triggers** databases. If we imagine a list as a table, we can imagine that an event is a trigger.

Then you can create a business rule associated with the creation, modification or deletion of an item.

You can also create events associated with other actions such as creating a site. A good way to generalize is to associate with content types, rather than list.

They are created with Visual Studio C #.